# How to use appendCells to append a list of columns in Google Sheets API

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using python 2.7 but my understanding is this syntax works with any language.

I'd like to append data to the bottom of my Google Sheets.  The function below works, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to:

1. specify `userEnteredValue` on the column level instead of cell level
2. not have to repeat the values list for each column.

An example with my current method:

```
def insertOneRecord(sheetId, value):
    data = {
     "requests": [
       {
         "appendCells": {
           "sheetId": sheetId,
           "rows": [  {"values": [
               {"userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": value[0]}},
               {"userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": value[1]}}
              ]}],
           "fields" : "userEnteredValue"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   res = SHEETS.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = SPREADSHEET_ID,body = data).execute()

values = ['O','P']
insertOneRecord(sheetId, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extraction of a code I'm working on. Maybe it could be helpful:

```
appendResult = spreadsheet.append(
    rangeName='%s!A3:D3' % title,
    values=values,
    valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
    insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
)
```

where `title` is the sheet **Name**, `values` is a tuple of tuples and `spreadsheet` is an instance of a custom class and the method `append` is this:

```
def append(self, rangeName, values, valueInputOption='RAW', insertDataOption='INSERT_ROWS'):
    self._log.debug("Inserting values starting from %s/%s" % (self.spreadsheetId, rangeName))
    return self._service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetId,
        range=rangeName,
        valueInputOption=valueInputOption,
        insertDataOption=insertDataOption,
        body={
            'values': values
        }
    ).execute()
```

`self._service` is the same service you can see in **Step 3** of [Google Sheets API - Python Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python), as the result of `discovery.build` function.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you follow all the OAuth consent.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

The documentation regarding is here. 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#append_empty_rows_or_columns

```
function InsertNewCol() { 
var requests = [];
requests.push({
    "appendDimension": {
        "range": {
           "dimension": "COLUMNS",
           "length": 3
        }
    }
});

gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
   spreadsheetId: 'YourSheetID',
   requests: requests
}).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});}
```